# Two Classes In Two Units With The Same Class Name in Delphi

Tags: delphi, namespaces

I have a case in Delphi such as:

- Unit `A` contains class `One`
- Unit `B` contains class `One`

I'm in a class that uses unit `A` and I want to use a static function from the class `One` in `B`; how can I do it?

In C#, I'd write something like:

```cs
B.One.SomeProcedure
```

Or even, I would use `using` to "rename" one namespace. What can I do in Delphi? Removing the `uses` for unit `A` is not an option, nor is renaming one of the two classes.

I'm using Delphi 2007.

Comment: If you just posted a cut down version of your code then we could tell you the solution instantly

Comment: The exact code doesn't really matter; the missing piece was that both units need to be in the "uses" clause. Coming from a C# background, this befuddled me until I figured it out. (C# allows fully qualified namespaces without importing other units.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following way: [UnitName].[Function]. For example B.SomeProcedure

Comment: I tried both B.SomeProcedure and B.One.SomeProcedure; both give me compilation errors

Comment: Unlike C#, the unit should still be in uses list, despite the fact that you are using a fully qualified name.

Comment: It would help to tell us which compilation errors you get. What Davita suggested definitely works.

Comment: That's the secret sauce -- you still have to put the declaration in "uses." Very unintuitive coming from a C# background. Cheers.

Comment: Well, I'd not compare C# to delphi, C# is far more superior :) Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly the same thing.  `UnitName.ClassName.Method`, just like in C#.

Comment: You need to have both units in the "uses" clause. That's confusing, because I'm used to C#, where you don't need to import both namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "a class that uses"? Maybe you mean "a unit that uses"? If so, you need to add both A and B to the `uses` clause. You can then distinguish between the two procedures by writing `A.One.SomeProcedure` or `B.One.SomeProcedure`. If you just write `One.SomeProcedure`, the procedure in the unit listed *last* in the `uses` clause will be used. [Here I assume that `One` are classes containing **class procedures** `SomeProcedure`. If `SomeProcedure` is an ordinary **procedure** of the `One` class, you need -- of course -- to create an object of this class and use this. You can then do `myobj := A.One.Create` or `myobj := B.One.Create`, where `var myobj: A.One` or `var myobj: B.One`, respectively.]

(Remember also that each unit contains *two* `uses` clauses: one at the beginning of the `interface` section and one at the beginning of the `implementation` section. If you use something from unit A at line *N*, the `uses` clause containing the unit A needs to be located on a line above *N*.)

Also notice that in Delphi, the class should be called `TOne`, with the `T` prefix. Everyone follows this convention, and it looks odd without it.

Comment: In Delphi 2007, it gives me compilation errors that A.SomeProcedure and B.SomeProcedure are undeclared identifiers.

Comment: Well, if `SomeProcedure` is a class procedure of `One`, then you need to write `A.One.SomeProcedure` or `B.One.SomeProcedure`, or `One.SomeProcedure`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for mentioning intricacies of using multiple units.

Answer (score 2):

how about TNewClassA = class(UnitA.One) and TNewClassB = class(UnitB.One)?

Comment: thank you, alltho' one should never be in a situation in which two types have the same name...

Comment: Agreed that this is an unhappy situation. It's also out of my power to refactor it. C# handles this nicely by letting you fully qualify namesapces. So does Delphi -- but you still need to put both units in "uses".