# Winapi.Windows naming conflict on TBitmap

Tags: delphi

The `Winapi.Windows` has a `TBitmap` type, but `Vcl.Graphics` has the same type name.

How can I resolve this conflict to be able to use the `Vcl.Graphics TBitmap`, but other functionalities of `Winapi.Windows` at the same time (the handle type in this case, but this is also a general question)?

---

**EDIT**: Someone marked this as a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340845/two-classes-in-two-units-with-the-same-class-name-in-delphi), but none of those answers worked for me.

Comment: You were unable to think from [`UnitName.Function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340860/4299358) to `UnitName.Type`? Surprise: full qualification solves a lot of problems.

Comment: you can switch around the units in the uses clause.

Comment: "*none of those answers worked for me*" - really? Because they do give the correct answer (ie, fully qualify the type names). So, you must not have read/understood/applied the answer correctly. Can you please [edit] your question to show EXACTLY what you tried that didn't work for you?

Comment: I said they did not work for me because I tried them. I changed my variable 'handle: HWND' to 'Winapi.Windows.HWND' and it didn't work. I also tried by putting only 'Winapi' or 'Winapi.Windows' in uses.

Comment: @PieterB What do you mean by "switching around the units" ? Does the unit order give preference to one type ?

Comment: Yes, the latest seen unit takes precedence. So if you have _USES WinAPI.Windows, VCL.Graphics;_ then use (unqualified) TBitMap, it'll take the one in VCL.Graphics but if you switch the order, it'll take the one in WinAPI.Windows.

Comment: According to [the official documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause), "The order in which units appear in the uses clause determines the order of their initialization and affects the way identifiers are located by the compiler. If two units declare a variable, constant, type, procedure, or function with the same name, the compiler uses the one from the unit listed last in the uses clause. (To access the identifier from the other unit, you would have to add a qualifier: UnitName.Identifier.)"

Comment: Okay, so the order of uses was actually my problem. Learn a weird new quirk everyday, I guess. Thanks !

Comment: What's weird or quirky about that? How would you (as a compiler) resolve the issue with the same identifier defined in two separate UNITs? (just curious)

Comment: @HeartWare by allowing both to be called by UnitName.Type, and raising a conflict error for both if they are used without prefix instead of assuming the last one is the one to use.

Comment: That would prevent interposer classes (subclassing VCL components).

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify the TBitmap name.

```
var
  MyBmp : Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap
```

Comment: Will Delphi still consider MyBmp and Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap to be the same type (In RTTI for example) ? I'm relying on the class name in a few places.

Comment: If you declared MyBmp as in my example, then yes Delphi considers MyBmp to be of this type (including Rtti)

Comment: This does not work when accessing constructor :
`buffer := Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Create(); // Error : "Vcl does not contain a member named 'Graphics'."`

Comment: @muchos: Do you USE _VCL.Graphics_ or just _Graphics_ (letting the compiler resolve the VCL namespace)? You must use the same name in your qualifier as you do in your USES statement. Or do you have a local (procedure/function/method or UNIT) variable named VCL?